# Chromecast extended cast - freeze then crash

Tags: javascript, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a slideshow application for my school to display posters and information for events. Ideally, it should be able to run on the chromecasts indefinitely, but over the course of a few minutes to up to 4 hours, the slideshow begins to lag before finally freezing. Soon, the chromecast closes the app and returns to the photowall.

- Here's the sender code:
  https://github.com/geosir/club-hub/blob/master/present/cast/index.html
- And the receiver code:
  https://github.com/geosir/club-hub/blob/master/present/receiver/index.html

I am using an iframe of my slideshow website (clubhub.studco.org/present) built in jQuery embedded in a modified version "HelloText-Chrome". Also, to stop the receiver from timing out and closing the connection, the sender periodically sends a message to the receiver to keep it awake.

I suspect that there is a memory leak somewhere in the code. I doubt that it's iframed site since it consumes a fairly constant amount of memory in my tests on Chrome. Could there be a problem with the way I'm handling the messages?

Any leads would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to profile your app and see where the leak is, it seems like a memory leak somewhere.

Comment: I'll get a new profile and come back with the results. In the past, the profile has shown some high memory usage, but garbage collection kicks in and reduces it again. Never has it exceeded 200MB The Chromecast is able to run fine across some peaks in memory, but why might it not be able to get across others?

Comment: I did end up getting the profile a while ago, but I don't have it anymore. The problem ended up having to do with the chromecast caching images on each reload (and I asked a question about it elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163208/chromecast-any-way-to-force-garbage-collection-cache-clear-during-runtime). Maybe in the future I'll make a more elegant fix, but for now I have a nasty workaround where I script the mouse to click the chromecast button and manually recast periodically. :P

Comment: Is this still the approach you are taking or have you found a better way to solve this issue? I am having the exact same problem with a chromecast application.

Comment: Yes, I'm still having this issue, and I'm still using the same hack to purge the cast cache via recasting described above. Perhaps hitting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36163208/chromecast-any-way-to-force-garbage-collection-cache-clear-during-runtime with an upvote or asking a new question will attract the Chromcast devs.